# API Call not successful

Tags: c#, api, sms

Good day Guys,

I am trying to Use an SMS API. Everything looks fine from my end but the SMS is not delivering. If i use the URL directly on Browser, it executes.

Or is anything wrong with how i built the string?
Below is the code.

Please Note tht cbo.Title is a comobox, txtFirstname is a Textbox.

```
public void NewText()
    {

            string username = "something@gmail.com";
            string password = "Password";
            string urlStr;
            string message=" Dear  " + cbo_Title.Text + "  " + txt_FirstName.Text + ",  Your New Savings Account Number is " + Account_No + ".Welcome to AGENTKUNLE Global Services.  Your Future is Our Priority ";
            string sender = "AGENTKUNLE";
            string recipient=txt_Phone.Text;
           urlStr = "https://portal.nigeriabulksms.com/api/?username="+username+"+password="+password+"+sender="+sender+"+message="+message+"+ mobiles="+recipient;

            Uri success  = new Uri(urlStr);


    }
```

Comment: This is the URL from the API owner. urlStr ="https://portal.nigeriabulksms.com/api/?username=username&password
=password&sender="&sender&"&message="&message&"&mobiles="&recipient

Comment: You're creating a URI, but you're not actually sending it anywhere! You might want to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) or [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure. Is it a `GET` or a `POST` request?

Comment: POST request will be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private string SendSms(string apiUrl)
{
    var targetUri = new Uri(apiUrl);
    var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(targetUri);
    webRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    try
    {
        string webResponse;
        using (var getresponse = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            var stream = getresponse.GetResponseStream();
            if (stream != null)
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    webResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            else
                webResponse = null;
            getresponse.Close();
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(webResponse?.Trim()))
            return webResponse.Trim();
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        ErrorHelper.Log(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHelper.Log(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        webRequest.Abort();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: you can use the above function for sending sms

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 1):

You never make a request.

The `Uri` object is just a container for the uri (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri)).
Check out the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) class if you want to send a request.